# R Multiplying each element of an array by a different number

Tags: arrays, r, multiplication

I am trying to multiply each element of an array by an integer (along the first dimension). The tricky thing is that this integer will change for each element.

An example :

```
test <- array(dim = c(3,5,7))
test[1,,] <- 1
test[2,,] <- 10
test[3,,] <- 100

vec <- c(1,2,3)
```

The result I want is an array with the same dimension (3,5,7) and along the first dimension :

```
test[1,,] * vec[1]
test[2,,] * vec[2]
test[3,,] * vec[3]
```

This means

```
Result <- array(dim = c(3,5,7))
Result[1,,] <- 1
Result[1,,] <- 20
Result[1,,] <- 300
```

I think I am quite close with different functions like outer or apply but I think there is an easier way, as I have a lot of data to treat. For now, I found the outer function, and I should select something like the diagonal of the result.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slice.index` might be helpful here

```
Result <- test * vec[slice.index(test, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
test*replicate(7, replicate(5, vec))
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using apply like this?

`sapply(1:length(vec), function(i) test[i,,]<<- test[i,,]*vec[i])`

Comment: Nothing really wrong I was just looking for a "nicer" way :) but it works ! I had trouble finding that as I was tempting to apply on the array and not the vector

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just do

```
Result <- test*vec
```

Note that this will only work if the dimension that is being split and multiplied is the first one.